# Nesting object declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

can someone help me with the following snippet.

```
type Item = {
    id: number;
    size: number;
}
type Example = {
    name: string;
    items: [
        Item
    ];
}

var obj: Example = {
    name: "test",
    items: [
        {
            id: 1,
            size: 10
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            size: 34
        }
    ]
}
```

Actually *items* should be a list of type *Item* but i got an error.

> Type '[{ id: number; size: number; }, { id: number; size: number; }]'
> is not assignable to type '[Item]'.   Source has 2 element(s) but
> target allows only 1.(2322)

Comment: Try maybe:
```type Example = {
    name: string;
    items:Item [];
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an array of `Item(s)` so you need to write `Item[]`.

```js
type Example = {
    name: string;
    items: Item[]
}
```

You can find out more about Array types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#Arrays).

> **Arrays:**
> To specify the type of an array like `[1, 2, 3]`, you can use the syntax `number[]`; this syntax works for any type (e.g. `string[]` is an array of strings, and so on).